# How can I prevent a controller from loading until a promise is resolved?

Tags: angularjs

Using UI.router, I can prevent *states* from loading before promises are resolved like so:

```
// Summary page
$stateProvider.state('home', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: '../home.html',
  controller: 'MainCtrl',
  resolve: {
    unitPromise: ['units',
     function (units) {
        return units.populate();
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

But I have a navigation bar that is not affiliated with a state since it is a shared view used on all pages.  I need to load a `user` object since I want to display the user's picture in the nav bar, and the url is stored in the user object.  However, the HTML loads before the NavCtrl has a chance to load the `user` model and pass it to the scope.  I also tried loading the user to `$rootScope` in `app.run`, but it still didn't load in time, and the html displayed the default image tag instead.

Comment: Why not to load the user in an higher component and let the navbar manage the user passed as its argument (by attribute for example) ?

Comment: Can you elaborate?  The navbar would be the first thing loaded if I'm not mistaken so I'm not sure what you mean by higher component

Comment: You may have a controller / component that wraps your navbar, and load your user in this higher order controller / component. Then you can just pass your user as an argument to your navbar. Your navbar will be dumber (and it's a good thing :D) and your app will work the same. This way your navbar will be displayed only when the higher order will be resolved

Comment: So in addition to the NavCtrl I already have, include another controller that encapsulates that?

Comment: Yes put one that wraps all the component / controller that have to share the user object and pass them the user resolved

Comment: I think this would be the same problem in which the html img tag would load before the link arrived.  Sorry if Im misunderstanding

Comment: Router resolver is the best way to deliver global dependency to Angular app. If you want this to be explained, please, provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question.